# In which case should one use header in the csv files to be imported to neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j

Is there some cases in which having headers in the csv files has significant advantage over not having them?

I am not sure about this but it seems that having using header is advantageous for huge data set: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be a little confused. There are multiple ways to import CSV files into neo4j.

The [neo4j-import(https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) tool, which you specifically ask about, *requires* headers, since they enable the tool to do its job.

On the other hand, the [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) Cypher clause supports but does not require headers. With `LOAD CSV`, I know of use cases in which NOT using headers is better. For example, in the non-header case each row of data would be provided in a string collection -- which can be very convenient if you wanted to iterate through all the columns, or store a collection of contiguous columns. Also, if you do not have a fixed number of columns, having headers may not even make sense.

Comment: but with the import tool you can also provide a separate, 1 line file that represents a header and allows you to reuse the same data csv file with several configs (e.g. as nodes and relationships)